How to Build More Realistic simulation Models Using MESA Agent-Based model and Reinforcement Q-Learning Methods?
I am working on a project to compare different modeling techniques for optimizing the waiting time of consumers at a movie theater. Specifically, I have created simple models using:
Discrete Event Simulation (DES)
Agent-Based Modeling (ABM)
Q-Learning based Reinforcement Learning
While the DES model produces realistic results where the waiting time changes accordingly when I modify parameters such as the number of customers and servers, the ABM and Q-Learning models do not exhibit similar behavior. In the ABM and Q-Learning models, the waiting time remains almost the same regardless of parameter changes.
Here is a brief overview of my implementations:
DES based using simpy
import simpy
import random
import statistics

wait_times = []

class Theater(object):
    def __init__(self, env, num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers):
        self.env = env
        self.cashier = simpy.Resource(env, num_cashiers)
        self.server = simpy.Resource(env, num_servers)
        self.usher = simpy.Resource(env, num_ushers)

    def purchase_ticket(self, moviegoer):
        yield self.env.timeout(random.randint(1, 3))

    def check_ticket(self, moviegoer):
        yield self.env.timeout(3 / 60)

    def sell_food(self, moviegoer):
        yield self.env.timeout(random.randint(1, 6))

def go_to_movies(env, moviegoer, theater):
    arrival_time = env.now

    # buy ticket
    with theater.cashier.request() as request:
        yield request
        yield env.process(theater.purchase_ticket(moviegoer))

    # check ticket
    with theater.usher.request() as request:
        yield request
        yield env.process(theater.check_ticket(moviegoer))

    # buy food
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        with theater.server.request() as request:
            yield request
            yield env.process(theater.sell_food(moviegoer))

    # go to their seat
    wait_times.append(env.now - arrival_time)

def run_theater(env, num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers, total_moviegoers):
    theater = Theater(env, num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers)
    moviegoer_id = 0

    for moviegoer in range(3):
        env.process(go_to_movies(env, moviegoer, theater))
        moviegoer_id += 1

    while moviegoer_id < total_moviegoers:
        yield env.timeout(0.20)
        env.process(go_to_movies(env, moviegoer_id, theater))
        moviegoer_id += 1

def calculate_wait_times(wait_times):
    average_wait = statistics.mean(wait_times)
    # pretty print results:
    minutes, frac_minutes = divmod(average_wait, 1)
    seconds = frac_minutes * 60
    return round(minutes), round(seconds)

def get_user_input():
    num_cashiers = 10
    num_servers = 20
    num_ushers = 5

    params = [num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers]

    if all(str(i).isdigit() for i in params):
        params = [int(x) for x in params]
    else:
        print(
            "Could not parse input. The simulation will use default values",
            "\n1 cashier, 1 server, 1 usher.",
        )
        params = [1, 1, 1]
    return params

def main():
    # Setup
    random.seed(42)
    num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers = get_user_input()
    total_moviegoers = 100  # Number of moviegoers to simulate

    # Run the simulation
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(run_theater(env, num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers, total_moviegoers))
    env.run()

    # View the results
    mins, secs = calculate_wait_times(wait_times)
    print(
        "Running simulation...",
        f"\nThe average wait time is {mins} minutes and {secs} seconds.",
        f"\nTotal number of moviegoers: {total_moviegoers}"
    )

main()

Agent based model using mesa implementation
from mesa import Agent, Model
from mesa.time import RandomActivation
from mesa.space import MultiGrid
from mesa.datacollection import DataCollector
import random

class MoviegoerAgent(Agent):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)
        self.wait_time = 0

    def step(self):
        # simulate arrival at the theater and the various steps
        self.buy_ticket()
        self.check_ticket()
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            self.buy_food()
        self.model.wait_times.append(self.wait_time)

    def buy_ticket(self):
        cashier = random.choice(self.model.cashiers)
        self.wait_time += random.randint(1, 3)
        cashier.busy = False

    def check_ticket(self):
        usher = random.choice(self.model.ushers)
        self.wait_time += 3 / 60
        usher.busy = False

    def buy_food(self):
        server = random.choice(self.model.servers)
        self.wait_time += random.randint(1, 6)
        server.busy = False

class TheaterAgent(Agent):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)
        self.busy = False

class TheaterModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers, num_moviegoers):
        self.num_agents = num_moviegoers
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)
        self.grid = MultiGrid(1, 1, False)
        self.wait_times = []

        # Create cashiers
        self.cashiers = []
        for i in range(num_cashiers):
            cashier = TheaterAgent(i, self)
            self.schedule.add(cashier)
            self.cashiers.append(cashier)

        # Create servers
        self.servers = []
        for i in range(num_cashiers, num_cashiers + num_servers):
            server = TheaterAgent(i, self)
            self.schedule.add(server)
            self.servers.append(server)

        # Create ushers
        self.ushers = []
        for i in range(num_cashiers + num_servers, num_cashiers + num_servers + num_ushers):
            usher = TheaterAgent(i, self)
            self.schedule.add(usher)
            self.ushers.append(usher)

        # Create moviegoers
        for i in range(num_moviegoers):
            moviegoer = MoviegoerAgent(i + num_cashiers + num_servers + num_ushers, self)
            self.schedule.add(moviegoer)

    def step(self):
        self.schedule.step()

def run_theater_simulation(num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers, num_moviegoers, num_steps):
    model = TheaterModel(num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers, num_moviegoers)
    for _ in range(num_steps):
        model.step()
    return model.wait_times

def calculate_average_wait_time(wait_times):
    average_wait = sum(wait_times) / len(wait_times)
    minutes, frac_minutes = divmod(average_wait, 1)
    seconds = frac_minutes * 60
    return round(minutes), round(seconds)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cashiers = 1
    num_servers = 2
    num_ushers = 1
    num_moviegoers = 100
    num_steps = 100

    wait_times = run_theater_simulation(num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers, num_moviegoers, num_steps)
    mins, secs = calculate_average_wait_time(wait_times)
    print(f"The average wait time is {mins} minutes and {secs} seconds.")



Q-learning based implementation
import numpy as np
import gym
from gym import spaces
import random

class TheaterEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers):
        super(TheaterEnv, self).__init__()
        self.num_cashiers = num_cashiers
        self.num_servers = num_servers
        self.num_ushers = num_ushers

        # Define action and observation space
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)  # Three actions: manage cashier, server, usher
        self.observation_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([num_cashiers + 1, num_servers + 1, num_ushers + 1])

        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        # Reset the state of the environment to an initial state
        self.state = [self.num_cashiers, self.num_servers, self.num_ushers]
        self.total_wait_time = 0
        self.steps = 0
        self.moviegoer_count = 0
        return np.array(self.state)

    def step(self, action):
        self.steps += 1
        done = self.steps >= 100

        if action == 0 and self.state[0] > 0:
            wait_time = random.randint(1, 3)
            self.state[0] -= 1
        elif action == 1 and self.state[1] > 0:
            wait_time = random.randint(1, 6)
            self.state[1] -= 1
        elif action == 2 and self.state[2] > 0:
            wait_time = 3 / 60
            self.state[2] -= 1
        else:
            wait_time = 1  # Penalty for invalid action

        self.total_wait_time += wait_time
        self.moviegoer_count += 1

        reward = -wait_time  # We want to minimize wait time
        return np.array(self.state), reward, done, {}

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        print(f"State: {self.state}, Total Wait Time: {self.total_wait_time}")

def q_learning(env, num_episodes=1000, learning_rate=0.1, discount_factor=0.99, epsilon=0.1):
    # Initialize Q-table with dimensions matching the state space
    q_table = np.zeros((env.observation_space.nvec[0], env.observation_space.nvec[1], env.observation_space.nvec[2], env.action_space.n))

    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        done = False

        while not done:
            if random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon:
                action = env.action_space.sample()  # Explore action space
            else:
                action = np.argmax(q_table[state[0], state[1], state[2]])  # Exploit learned values

            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

            old_value = q_table[state[0], state[1], state[2], action]
            next_max = np.max(q_table[next_state[0], next_state[1], next_state[2]])

            new_value = (1 - learning_rate) * old_value + learning_rate * (reward + discount_factor * next_max)
            q_table[state[0], state[1], state[2], action] = new_value

            state = next_state

    return q_table

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cashiers = 10
    num_servers = 100
    num_ushers = 1

    env = TheaterEnv(num_cashiers, num_servers, num_ushers)
    q_table = q_learning(env, num_episodes=100)

    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    total_wait_time = 0
    moviegoer_count = 0

    while not done:
        action = np.argmax(q_table[state[0], state[1], state[2]])
        state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        total_wait_time += -reward  # Reward is negative of wait time
        moviegoer_count += 1

    average_wait_time = total_wait_time / moviegoer_count

    # Calculate minutes and seconds
    average_wait_time_minutes = int(average_wait_time)
    average_wait_time_seconds = int((average_wait_time - average_wait_time_minutes) * 60)

    print(f"Total moviegoers served: {moviegoer_count}")
    print(f"Average wait time after Q-learning: {average_wait_time_minutes} minutes and {average_wait_time_seconds} seconds")

How can I make the ABM and Q-Learning models more realistic, similar to the DES model? What techniques or modifications can I apply to ensure that the waiting time in ABM and Q-Learning models changes appropriately with different parameter values?
Any insights, suggestions, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
